# How to unlock superuser 'postgres' account in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, database

While connecting to the `pgadmin` database postgres with correct password, I'm getting the following error:

```
'Error connecting to the server:FATAL password authentication failed with user 'postgres'.
```

After changing the method to `'trust'` instead of `'md5'` in `hba` config file, and then typed:

```
 ALTER USER POSTGRES WITH PASSWORD 'newpassword'
```

after again changing the methods as md5 then tried connecting to database

Howerver the password  changed successfully (I checked in encrypt mode and it was fine) but getting the same issue:

```
 'Error connecting to the server:FATAL password authentication failed with user 'postgres'.
```

Kindly suggest me if there are any other solution for this issue.

Comment: FYI - this question is on-topic for [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com)

Comment: What are the entries in your pg_hba.conf file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This suggests to me that either you are authenticating against an outside source (not common) or somehow you have been bitten by a bug in pgAdmin that set validto to an invalid date (more common).

Try this:

```
ALTER USER postgres VALID UNTIL 'infinity';
```

Or you can set the valid until value to something more limited if you want to lock the account after a certain time period.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your kind response, it is working very fine and i could able to login pgadmin without any issues.